# click event inside of <tr tag

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Not really sure how to write a test statement when a click event is inside of a tr tag < tr > < tr>. Using Jest and Enzyme for my tests

Here is the click event:

```
<tr id = 'getContext-clicktest'onClick={this.editContext.bind(this, c)} key={c.ContextParameterId} className='user-table-row'>
   <td>{c.PARAMETER_TYPE.Name}</td>
   <td>{c.ParameterLabel}</td>
   <td>{c.Parameter}</td>
   <td>{c.PARAMETER_DATATYPE.Name}</td>
   <td>{c.Choices ? c.Choices : 'N/A'}</td>
</tr>
```

Here is how I am setting up my test file, 
using mount instead of shallow to render my components.

```
beforeEach(() => wrapper = mount(<ContextComponent {...baseProps} />));

it('should call getContext method on button click', () => {
 wrapper.setState({ 
   currentContext: {
   PARAMETER_TYPE:{
      ParameterTypeId:""
      },
  PARAMETER_DATATYPE:{
      DataTypeId:""
      },
},
 showEditContextModal: true,
});
wrapper.find('tr').find('#getContext-clicktest').simulate('click')
});
```

Comment: if you're asking for testing event bubbling(e.g. to ensure handler is called even on clicking `td` nested instead of `tr`) it's not possible in enzyme so far. or is it a question how to test click handlers in general?

Comment: I do know how to test some of the click handlers but i never did on td or tr. So now i know that is not possible, how can i do it /

Comment: @skyboyer when theres a <select tag, is it a different rule ?  for example :      wrapper.find('select').find('#update-form-id').simulate('change',

Answer (score 1):

[`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) creates a new function each time it is called so every time your component renders it creates a new function and binds it to `onClick`.

Because of this, it isn't possible to spy on the `onClick` function directly...

...but the new function gets bound to the function on the prototype of your component class, so if you wrap the prototype function with a spy before your component renders, the `onClick` function will be bound to your spy.

Here is a simplified example:

code.js

```js
import * as React from 'react';

export class TableComponent extends React.Component {

  edit(c) { }

  render() {
    const { c } = this.props;
    return (
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr id='clicktest' onClick={this.edit.bind(this, c)} key={c.id}>
            <td>{c.name}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
```

code.test.js

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

import { TableComponent } from './code';

let wrapper, editSpy;

beforeEach(() => {
  editSpy = jest.spyOn(TableComponent.prototype, 'edit');
  wrapper = mount(<TableComponent c={{ id: 1, name: 'one' }} />)
});

afterEach(() => {
  editSpy.mockRestore();
})

it('should call getContext method on button click', () => {
  wrapper.find('#clicktest').simulate('click');
  expect(editSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and and answer Brian, but  ill have to work around it . Getting 2 errors which I expected already :    TypeError: Cannot read property 'mockRestore' of undefined and  Cannot read property '_isMockFunction' of undefined